What are the pros / cons of having the main domain + sub domains under one google search console profile?
Background -
Im managing a site which is :

main site - main wordpress site

subdomain 1 - tumblr blog

subdomain 2 - a custom mini web app


Ive added the main domain to Google Search Console (GSC) which has auto added all the pages for the sub domains also.
This seems quite a messy way to do it, as each of the 3 domains above is a mini site in iteself.
Question 1 - Is there any benefit of having the main domain and the sub domains combined under 1 GSC profile ?
Question 2 - If i wanted to split them out how could i do this ?

Question 1: Is there any benefit of having the main domain and the subdomains combined under one GSC profile?
Answer 1
It seems obvious that the main advantage is that all the data is in one place, making it easier and more convenient to compare various metrics. I couldn't think of any other significant benefits, but this one already seems important enough :)
However, the drawbacks can also be significant:

It might be challenging to separate data by subdomains, which can complicate analysis, especially if the subdomains target different audiences, for example.

Theoretically, you might miss an important issue with one of the subdomains because it might be less noticeable within the larger volume of data across all sites.


Question 2: If I wanted to split them out, how could I do this?
Answer 2
This is straightforward; here's the guide:

Adding a new property in Google Search Console:

Go to the Google Search Console homepage.
Click on the "Add property" button and enter the URL of your subdomain (e.g., https://subdomain1.example.com).
Choose a verification method (e.g., adding a meta tag to the HTML code, uploading an HTML file, using Google Analytics, or DNS verification).


Verifying the subdomain*:

Follow Google’s instructions for the selected verification method. The subdomain will be considered verified once Google can confirm that you own or manage the resource.



You can refer to the full guide: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592.

GSC does have some functionality that can only be used within a URL property, as opposed to a domain property. You can easily have both within the same account. This gives you all of the functionality to manually inspect/manage each subdomain (as well as the main website), while having the benefits of the domain property to have an overview of everything.
